# Select statement after insert hangs?

Tags: t-sql

In my stored procedure I am trying to insert records in to a temporary table

In my stored procedure I am trying to insert records in to a temporary table

```
--Temporary table
create table #CR_TMP
    (

         ct_co_id               int        NULL 
         , ct_nbr               int        NULL 
         , ctrct_srvc_type         char(4)    NULL 
     , start_date          datetime   NULL 
     , end_date            datetime   NULL 
    )

  print 'Before insert' 

Insert into #CR_TMP
 select distinct col1,col2,......
from tableName
where conditions

print 'After insert'
select '#CR_TMP' as #CR_TMP, * from #CR_TMP
print 'here 1'
```

I ran the select query and it gives about 583 rows.
But when I execute the above procedure. I think it's getting stuck on the insert procedure.
I do get the result 'After insert' but I don't get the results for print 'here 1'. 
I had this procedure executing for 2 hours and it was stuck at the same place. Any pointers here?

I ran the select query and it gives about 583 rows.
But when I execute the above procedure. I think it's getting stuck on the insert procedure.
I do get the result 'After insert' but I don't get the results for print 'here 1'. 
I had this procedure executing for 2 hours and it was stuck at the same place. Any pointers here?

Comment: You seem to have given everything in that select statement the name `#CR_TMP`. Try changing it to something like: `select '#CR_TMP' as CR_TMP, * from #CR_TMP`. I think you may have inadvertently caused an infinite loop here.

Comment: After the debug ,I don't know what's wrong with the select statement.if I say select * from #CRVC1400_TMP 
         select * from #CRVC1400_TMP
             select * from #CRVC1400_TMP.The last select statement goes in a loop. In this case the first 2 select with give results quickly but the last select will keep on executing infinitely. Any pointers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure looks good except for this part:

```
print 'After insert'
select '#CR_TMP' as #CR_TMP, * 
from #CR_TMP
print 'here 1'
```

Try changing this to:

```
print 'After insert'
select '#CR_TMP' as [#CR_TMP], * 
from #CR_TMP
print 'here 1'
```

Or even remove the first part of the `select`

```
print 'After insert'
select * 
from #CR_TMP
print 'here 1'
```

Edit:

After a discussion in chat, it was determined that the initial portion of the stored procedure that sanika thought was the issue actually was working. So I advised that they start working query by query back into a test to determine where the actual problem is.  At that point, it will be easier to debug a 30 page stored procedure.

Comment: Tried both the options still the same

Comment: @sanika is the full procedure shown above the one that you are running?

Comment: I would only try running the one statement that appears to be hanging. Or post your full procedure for review.

Comment: The whole proc is huge, like 30 pages. But this is the very first insert statemnet in the proc. There are bunch of create tables statements before this insert query though.

Comment: I would advise pulling this one statement out and see if it completes.  It could be that something after this is causing the problem.

Comment: The select query works. In that case the print statement here1 should be printed

Comment: Another insert in the same temporary table

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the entire procedure and then some of the data is it very difficult to debug the problem.  Can you post some sample data and a longer piece of the procedure?

Comment: Let me make a shorter version of the proc

Comment: I have posted the updated proc  exec CRVC1400_DRV 29567,'CRVC1400',000001,'04/01/2012','08/16/2012','I','P','ALL','ALL','ALL'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15468/discussion-between-bluefeet-and-sanika)